# Firebase Database Data Structure and using Rules

Tags: arrays, swift, data-structures, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have an app which retrieves an array of users within a certain radius (using GeoFire) however, my app needs to dismiss these users if they are not applicable.  Therefore, I now have two arrays.

Array (1) users within a radius

Array (2) users that have been dismissed

My question, and sorry for the long windedness is that what is the most efficient way of removing Array (2) from (1)? As both arrays could have hundreds of items in.  If I filter the arrays this will surely be an inefficient & slow way of getting the final array.

I did have a lightbulb moment when I stumbled across some of Firebase Database Rules examples.  Could I possibly create a child in Firebase Database with all the non-applicable users and then have the rules have them as "!= .read"?

Reading through the doc's on Rules it states that Rules are not filters.  However, I don't see any efficient way of filtering the arrays.

As always any help appreciated.

Adding current Data Structure:

```
{
  "not_applicable" : {
"yhgeZLXJhuXKmbnK1eRwkC4xmO83" : {
  "yhgeZLXJhuXKmbnK1eRwkC4xmO84" : "",
  "yhgeZLXJhuXKmbnK1eRwkC4xmO85" : "",
  "yhgeZLXJhuXKmbnK1eRwkC4xmO87" : "",
  "yhgeZLXJhuXKmbnK1eRwkC4xmO88" : "",
  "yhgeZLXJhuXKmbnK1eRwkC4xmO89" : "",
  "yhgeZLXJhuXKmbnK1eRwkC4xmO90" : ""
}
  },
  "locations" : {
"yhgeZLXJhuXKmbnK1eRwkC4xmO83" : {
  ".priority" : "9q9hrh5sdd",
  "g" : "9q9hrh5sdd",
  "l" : [ 37.33233141, -122.0312186 ]
},
"yhgeZLXJhuXKmbnK1eRwkC4xmO84" : {
  ".priority" : "9q9hrh5sdd",
  "g" : "9q9hrh5sdd",
  "l" : [ 37.33233141, -102.0312186 ]
},
"yhgeZLXJhuXKmbnK1eRwkC4xmO85" : {
  ".priority" : "9q9hrh5sdd",
  "g" : "9q9hrh5sdd",
  "l" : [ 37.33141, -122.0312186 ]
},
"yhgeZLXJhuXKmbnK1eRwkC4xmO86" : {
  ".priority" : "9q9hrh5sdd",
  "g" : "9q9hrh5sdd",
  "l" : [ 37.33233141, "-38.2333" ]
},
"yhgeZLXJhuXKmbnK1eRwkC4xmO87" : {
  ".priority" : "9q9hrh5sdd",
  "g" : "9q9hrh5sdd",
  "l" : [ 37.33233141, -132.0312186 ]
},
"yhgeZLXJhuXKmbnK1eRwkC4xmO88" : {
  ".priority" : "9q9hrh5sdd",
  "g" : "9q9hrh5sdd",
  "l" : [ 37.33233141, -122.0312186 ]
},
"yhgeZLXJhuXKmbnK1eRwkC4xmO89" : {
  ".priority" : "9q9hrh5sdd",
  "g" : "9q9hrh5sdd",
  "l" : [ 37.33233141, -122.0312186 ]
},
"yhgeZLXJhuXKmbnK1eRwkC4xmO90" : {
  ".priority" : "9q9hrh5sdd",
  "g" : "9q9hrh5sdd",
  "l" : [ 37.33233141, -122.0312186 ]
}
  },
  "users" : {
"yhgeZLXJhuXKmbnK1eRwkC4xmO83" : {
  "email" : “someEmail”,
},
"yhgeZLXJhuXKmbnK1eRwkC4xmO84" : {
  "email" : "someEmail",
},
"yhgeZLXJhuXKmbnK1eRwkC4xmO85" : {
  "email" : "someEmail",
},
"yhgeZLXJhuXKmbnK1eRwkC4xmO86" : {
  "email" : "someEmail",
},
"yhgeZLXJhuXKmbnK1eRwkC4xmO87" : {
  "email" : "someEmail",
},
"yhgeZLXJhuXKmbnK1eRwkC4xmO88" : {
  "email" : "someEmail",
},
"yhgeZLXJhuXKmbnK1eRwkC4xmO89" : {
  "email" : "someEmail",
},
"yhgeZLXJhuXKmbnK1eRwkC4xmO90" : {
  "email" : "someEmail",
}
  }
}
```

I am logged in as user "yhgeZLXJhuXKmbnK1eRwkC4xmO83" I run a query for .keyEntered in geoFire as below.

```
func runQuery(location: CLLocation) {

    let query = geoFire?.query(at: location, withRadius: Double(2000))

    query?.observe(.keyEntered, with: { (key:String!, location: CLLocation!) in

        self.getResults(key: key)

    })

        query?.observeReady({

        //MARK: - geoFire Query Observe Ready Something Missing Here :(
            print("Observe geoFire Ready")

    })
}
```

I get those keys and search through the users in the database using self.getResults(key: key) as below

```
private func getResults(key: String!) {

    userRef.child(key).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        let snapshotResult = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject]

        let userProfileURL = snapshotResult?["profileURL"] as! String
        let userName = snapshotResult?["name"] as! String
        let uid = snapshot.ref.key

        let aRequest = UserResults(userName: userName,
                                   userProfileURL: userProfileURL,
                                   uid: uid)

        self.userResults.append(aRequest)

        self.filteredUserResults = self.userResults.filter {

            $0.uid != self.userID
        }
    })
}
```

However, once the user has decided that a user result is not applicable it mustn't come back into the results.  It must be referenced somewhere.  I.e in Array (2) as mentioned above.

Comment: I find it hard to parse your question in its current form. Instead of describing your data structure and approach, can you edit the question to include the [minimal JSON and code that reproduce where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen updated code & current data structure.  Hope this helps

Comment: It helps, but I'm still not certain of what you're asking. Is the question how to skip the `not_applicable` items in your query or callback?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen correct.  I want to exclude all the "not_applicable" keys in the self.getResults func or earlier in the code if possible.  Just not sure how to structure the data to provide the solution. I could get a snapshot of the "not_applicables" and store it into an array and then reference that array against UserResults but wouldn't that give poor performance if there are 1,000's of objects in UserResults?

Comment: There is no way to do that in a database query, so you'll have to do it client side. That will indeed become a scalability limit as you have more and more items in those lists The alternative would be to keep geodata for each of your target users, i.e. perform a fan-out to each user on write. That way the performance hit comes upon writing the data, instead of reading the data.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I see.  So if I understand you correctly...  Once I get the users location it searches for everyone within the radius then with that, I can update under their uid some where and perhaps use a bool for applicable/non-applicable under that uid?